# Sort rows of a Pandas DataFrame based on aggregated count and get one row randomly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas DataFrame with columns like this:

`col1       col2    col3    col4   col5`

`a            a1    foo1    foo2   foo3`

`b            b1    foo4    foo5   foo6`

`c            c1    foo7    foo8   foo9`

`a            a2    foo10    foo11   foo12`

`a            a3    foo13    foo14   foo15`

`b            b2    foo16    foo17   foo18`

I would like to sort the rows (the entire rows) of this dataframe based on descending frequency of values in `col1` and then for other columns in the row, get one of the rows that have that value in their column (similar to SQL group by). How can I do that in Pandas? I believe this is some combination of groupby and sort_values, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it.

For the above example, `a` is the most frequent value in `col1`, followed by `b` and `c`. So I would like the first row of the resulting dataframe to be one of the rows with `col1` value being `a`. The next row should be one of the two rows with value `b`. And the last row is the only row having value `c`.

So this is one answer:

`col1       col2    col3    col4   col5`

`a            a1    foo1    foo2   foo3`

`b            b1    foo4    foo5   foo6`

`c            c1    foo7    foo8   foo9`

but so is this one:

`col1       col2    col3    col4   col5`

`a            a3    foo13    foo14   foo15`

`b            b1    foo4    foo5   foo6`

`c            c1    foo7    foo8   foo9`

And this one:

`col1       col2    col3    col4   col5`

`a            a2    foo10    foo11   foo12`

`b            b2    foo16    foo17   foo18`

`c            c1    foo7    foo8   foo9`

Any of these is fine as the result. To be more clear, mixing of values from different rows is not allowed. A row must be returned exactly as is.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52188764/edit) to include a **[mcve]**?

Comment: what do you expect your output to be? Your input df is also blank, you should give us a bit more to work with.

Comment: @d_kennetz Added more explanation.

Comment: @jpp Added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you could do this:

1) Create a helper series using `Series.value_counts` to get the order

2) Index your original df with this helper series and drop duplicate `col1` values.

```
s = df.col1.value_counts()
df.set_index('col1').loc[s.index].reset_index().drop_duplicates('col1')
```

or in one line:

```
df2 = (df.set_index('col1')
       .loc[df.col1.value_counts().index]
       .reset_index()
       .drop_duplicates('col1'))
```

[Output]

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
0   a       a1      foo1    foo2    foo3
3   b       b1      foo4    foo5    foo6
5   c       c1      foo7    foo8    foo9
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives the correct answer, but is very slow for my dataframe (about 17 million records). Are there faster ways to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty straightforward way to do this, first sort by col1, then drop duplicates:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('funky.csv')
df.sort_values('col1', ascending=True, inplace=True)
df
```

output for part 1:

```
  col1 col2   col3   col4   col5
0    a   a1   foo1   foo2   foo3
3    a   a2  foo10  foo11  foo12
4    a   a3  foo13  foo14  foo15
1    b   b1   foo4   foo5   foo6
5    b   b2  foo16  foo17  foo18
2    c   c1   foo7   foo8   foo9
```

then simply drop duplicates in column1:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(['col1'])
df2
```

output:

```
  col1 col2  col3  col4  col5
0    a   a1  foo1  foo2  foo3
1    b   b1  foo4  foo5  foo6
2    c   c1  foo7  foo8  foo9
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this will only sort the df alphabetically... It won't sort it by frequency.

Comment: Yes, I upvoted your answer as it is better! Thanks for the heads up.